# "slightly/somewhat" の 「～[目]{め}」: Usage and limitations

Tags: grammar, usage, suffixes

I'm somewhat confused about the usage and limitations of the　～め　suffix that means "somewhat/slightly".  I've only ever heard it on a handful of words:

> - 大きめ
> - 小さ目
> - 多め
> - 少な目
> - 早め

and maybe a few others that I can't recall at present.

1) Can these be used with any イ-adjectives, or only certain ones?
2) Can they be used with ナ-adjectives at *all*?  Can't say I've ever seen one.
3) What are the limitations of its usage?  For the イ-adjectives, is ～めに interchangeable with ～く for forming the adverb?
4) などなど

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Yes. There seems to be no limitation on the combination of i-adjectives and `目`.
2. Yes. For example, `静かめの曲`
3. It is not interchangable. As you already wrote in the question, `目` weakens the attribute expressed by the adjective. Therefore, the adverbial usage `...目に` will in general be a weakening of the adverbial usage of `...く`.

   > - 早く走った 'ran early'
   > - 早めに走った 'ran somewhat early'
4. ???