# How is 高めの used and constructed?

Tags: grammar, translation

example sentence: コレステロールが高めの方の食品

I'd like to know how 高めの is made (verb stem + no?) and how it should be used. I'm guessing the example sentence means "food which heightens your cholesterol". Does 方 mean type/category here?

Comment: You are seeing another word 方（ほう）.  This is 方（かた） = "person(s)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `〜め` is the one meaning "slightly" or "somewhat", and the `方` is "people".  So the sentence translates as "Foods that people with high(er than normal) cholesterol (eat)".  It would probably sound more serious if it were just `高い`, but using `〜め` it sounds more of just a neutral magazine (pamphlet, etc.) headline.

As for the `の`, that's needed to modify `方`.  With, `高い`, it would just be `高い方`, but `高め` is not an イ-adjective, so it requires the `の`: `高めの方`.

See also this post:  [“slightly/somewhat” の 「～目」: Usage and limitations](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2037/78).