# Grammatical explanation of 高めだし

Tags: grammar, meaning

I found the word 高めだし and I guess it means "really expensive" or something similar. How does it work grammatically? Can -めだし be used after any -i adjective? And what does it mean? Does it come from the verb 目立つ? If yes, shouldn't it be -めだち?
Thanks for your help!

Context:

> えっ！？でもそのショップって何でも高めだし！

Comment: This is also related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14560/5010

Comment: @naruto He is confused about the usage of だし the 2 links provided will be of little help to make him understand.

Comment: @stackreader Thank you, well, I intended to just vote, not to directly close... Nevertheless, obviously OP is getting the め part wrong. And judging from his previous questions, I doubt he doesn't understand だし. For now, let me keep this marked as duplicate and see what OP thinks.

Comment: I considered "-めだし" as a suffix, but now it's clear that it isn't. I wasn't able to break it down as "高め - だ - し" as explained by stack reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

高め means kinda high (expensive).
だ is just casual です.
し (at the end of a phrase) notes one (of several) reasons.

The sentence seems to mean that the talker don't want to go because among other things, the shop is too expensive.

Comment: As I read [here](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2037/slightly-somewhat-%E3%81%AE-%EF%BD%9E%E7%9B%AE%E3%82%81-usage-and-limitations) the suffix -め means "slightly", so it actually weakens the attribute expressed by the adjective, right?