# Trying to figure out 激し目なのばっか乗せて回った

Tags: meaning

> こいつが小さい頃、遊園地で**激し目なのばっか乗せて回った**からだ。

This part gives me trouble. What does 激し目 mean? What about なのばっか and 乗せて回る?

Context: he's explaining why his son doesn't like planes.

Comment: It means that when his son was smaller, he used to make him ride the turbulent/intense rides in the amusement park. 激し目 means the turbulent/intense ones, in contrast to the slow, easy ones. ばっか is just ばっかり and 乗せて回る well you can guess already.

Comment: yes, but please avoid putting answers in the comments area. It's not proper stack exchange etiquette.

Comment: For the 目: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2037/9831

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「激{はげ}し目{め}なのばっか乗{の}せて回{まわ}った。」

Where should I start?

> 「i-adjective -(minus) い +(plus) め/目」 means "***rather [adjective]***", "***[adjective] in a more/less than average way***", etc.

「激し目」, therefore, means "***rather intense***", "***more extreme than average***", etc. since this context is clearly about amusement park rides.

(I like wearing 大き目のT-シャツ.  大きい - い + 目 = 大き目.  )

「の」 is a nominalizer, so 「激し目な**の**」 means "***the more intense ones***" with the "ones" referring to the park rides.

「ばっか」 is the colloquial way of saying 「ばかり」("***only***").  In informal speech, you will also often hear 「ばっかり」 and 「ばっかし」 as well.

「乗せて回った」 means "***I used to made him ride a whole bunch*** (of the more intense rides)."　「Verb in te-form + まわる」 means "to (verb) repeatedly".

So, the sentence means:

> "That's because when he was little, I used to make him ride only the more intense ones/rides at the amusement parks."

Comment: Would "あの女は可愛目なんだな。" be correct?

Comment: it seems weird to me to use this construct in reference to people, but that could just be because I've never heard it done before. ... "She's rather cute." sounds fine, but I envision 目 usage as translating more "colloquially" to "on the X side" so あの女は可愛目なんだな。would be like "She's a bit on the cute side, eh?" ... technically I guess it works, but something feels off. I think people would more naturally say あの子はけっこ可愛いだな。Maybe I'm wrong though. Maybe it's totally normal to use the comparative 目 in describing people...

Comment: Actually I also think it feels a bit strange, I wonder why it doesn't work in this particular case.