# What does adjective + め means

Tags: meaning, adjectives, suffixes

On this informational sign in ramen shop they use -i adjectives ending with め. I can understand plain かたい, 多い and such, but what purpose does ending an adjective in め serves?

[image]

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2037/slightly-somewhat-%e3%81%ae-%ef%bd%9e%e7%9b%ae%e3%82%81-usage-and-limitations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definition 17 on [Jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E7%9B%AE%20):

> 17. somewhat; -ish

So, かため means on cooked a bit on the hard side, やわらかめ on cooked a bit on the soft side, etc