# What does ます stem + に mean?

Tags: grammar

> 昨日より、強めに怒られたのだろう

In this sentence specificly, Apparently it means "was scolded more strongly than yesterday" based on the context but does it mean that you can use a ます stem of a verb + に to make it an adverb? Or is it related to the ます stem + に + 行く (to go for the purpose of doing something) but with just a different verb?

Comment: There is no verb in 強めに.

Comment: ＠l'électeur I tried to find in dictionaries in both Japanese and English if it's an adverb or adjective but I can only find it being a verb. So is it an adverb then?

Comment: Related: [“slightly/somewhat" の 「～目」: Usage and limitations](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2037/43676)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can not join ます + に, but you can join na-adjective/noun + に.

You are confused because you are thinking of 強め as a verb, but it is not. The verb is 強める, not 強め. 強め is the 連用形 (or ます stem) of the verb. Take a look at the second entry for 強め at [this weblio page](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A4%E3%82%88%E3%82%81) (emphasis mine):

> マ行下一段活用の動詞「強める」の連用形、**あるいは連用形が名詞化したもの**。Conjunctive form of an ichidan verb in the マ column, **or alternatively, nominalization of the conjunctive form**.

While it's true that 強める is a verb, what you are seeing in the sentence under discussion is a *nominalization* of the 連用形 (or ます stem) of this verb, i.e. 強め is being treated as a noun. Consequently, you can add に to it just as you would do with any noun and turn it into an adverb.

Note that this is not to say that any 連用形 form (or ます stem) of a verb can deliberately be nominalized, but other nominalizations come to my mind such as 出来上がり (from 出来上がる).

> Or is it related to the ます stem + に + 行く (to go for the purpose of doing something) but with just a different verb?

It is not related to the grammar (ます stem) + に + 行く.

Comment: これは、動詞の連用形の「強め」じゃなくて、形容詞の語幹に付く接尾辞の「[目]{め}」でしょう。「いつもより**早め**に学校に行く」「 **大きめ**のみじん切り」「血圧が**高め**の人」「ご飯**少なめ**にしてください」とかいうときの。